# how to upload file to Amazon S3 based on angularjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I am trying to using the module: https://github.com/asafdav/ng-s3upload
I followed the steps they listed, when I come to the forth step, It provides me the ruby example for creating a local service, I am not familiar with ruby on rails, could someone do me a favor on how to use the ruby code?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should post the questions in project github, and people will be happy to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any serverside languages like express js, asp.net c#, java, etc.

The point is that to render secret information from server side in Json format.